# OpenFileActivityBuilder to select multiples files

Tags: android, api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, drive

I search in google developers documentation if has a way to OpenFileActivityBuilder to select multiples files, but I didn't find anything.

So, someone knows how allow user selects more than one files with open file activity, and return the DriveID of each one?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't currently supported, however it's something we are aware of and would like to add in future.